# How can I improve the topology of this object

Tags: modeling, retopology

So I made this object. But when I try to smooth it I can see some weird issues in the geometry.
How can I improve the retopology to make those issues disappear?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks to me the problem lies with the gentle curve of the mesh. The verts that make the inner shape don't follow the shape of the curve precisely. You can fix it using the shrinkwrap modifier, it's a super handy trick!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1C9z1CwZWEQ

Comment: The shrinkwrap modifier does help, but it doesn't completely fix the problem.
https://i.ibb.co/7z5b4mt/Screenshot-4.jpg

Comment: Can you share your .blend?
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Another approach is to flatten the mesh (select all verts, S, Y, 0) add a subsurf mod to up the poly count, then use a Simple Deform modifier to get the curve back. It depends on what you final result needs to be.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=DpBN2l5Q" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DpBN2l5Q/)

I prefer to avoid adding more polygons if I can. I started with 64 sided cylinder, and I think 128 sided cylinder would give a cleaner result, although it will be heavier on the polycount, and this shape is a part of a bigger object.

Final results is supposed to look like this-  https://i.ibb.co/vksVGgH/Screenshot-5.jpg

Comment: You're gonna need a lot more geo than that if you want a nice curve with an odd shaped hole in it. Anywhere that the geo does not remain a nice flow of evenly spaced quads the subsurf or shade smooth will have shading artifacts or will pull the mesh in weird ways.
This is how I would do this for perfect smooth shape. Of course if you apply the boolean you will have to go in and do a manual clean up.
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/yWL31Dwx/

Answer (score 3):

From one sub-d way of looking at it, you've got 2 curvatures to capture: the one around the hole, and the one around the cylinder. To keep the cylindrical curve even, it should consist of edges parallel to the bend, as evenly spaced as possible.

So one approach, working in the flat, before bending the piece, is to try to capture the curvature of the hole using only cuts into the lines which will be parallel to the bend...

[image]

.. also isolating the hole from the bend by making it the result of an inset: puting a rim of faces around its perimeter.

Working under  *Mirror* and a *Subdivision* modifiers, you can see the curves you will wind up with.

The rules aren't hard and fast.. you can bend the up-down lines a little, and add edges *around* the cylinder wherever they help you out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Psyonic you could use a Shrinkwrap modifier:

- Improve your topology a bit (or keep it as it is but it may create a bit of pinching):

[image]

- Create a sphere, make it big enough, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with a level of 3:

[image]

- Give to your object a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the sphere as *Target*, add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier if necessary:

[image]